# "There's a bear here"- is there a better way to say it?

Tags: there-is

It is very common for people to say something like "There's a bear here".  However, I don't think that this is correct, because a bear cannot be both "there" and "here" at the same time (barring any creative physics concepts).

Is there some better way to say it?  "Here's a bear" sounds like I'm presenting a bear as a gift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"There" has a rather more complex set of meanings than simply "a place not near me".  In this case it's being used as a placeholder for the delayed subject ("a bear") of the verb "to be" (being used in the sense of existing rather than as a copula).  It has no sense of location to it in this usage.

So "There is a bear here." is equivalent to "A bear is (exists) here.", which you could use as an alternative if you prefer.

For more details: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/there#Pronoun

Comment: It's clearer in French: Existential _there_ (+ is): Il y a (un ours) // Locative _there_ (+ is): Voilà (un ours)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think *there's a bear* would mean *there's a problem.* Apart from that, the sentence is grammatical but may not mean what you have in mind. You could say,

> The homework was a bear. Which is a slang way of saying it was difficult.

If your question is about the *here* part in your sentence, then I'd say it's better to remove the last *here* because it doesn't add any substance to the meaning of your sentence.

Comment: Oh, I actually didn't mean to say that a bear is a problem.  I meant the part about mixing "there" and "here" together in the sentence.  But what I mean is that in colloquial English (at least in my own experience) it seems that we would add the "here" to say that the bear is actually _here_, and not just floating off somewhere.

Comment: @SimonT It's not just in colloquial English but seems to be wide spread in contemporary literature.